# Shiny radio button not getting rendered initially when the app starts

Tags: r, shiny

I am doing some timeseries analysis and have created a shiny app where when the app starts sample timeseries data is uploaded or the user can upload csv dataset from his local directory....

Sample Dataset:

```
df
         month passengers
1  01-01-2000    2072798
2  01-02-2000    2118150
3  01-03-2000    2384907
4  01-04-2000    2260620
5  01-05-2000    2386165
6  01-06-2000    2635018
7  01-07-2000    2788843
8  01-08-2000    2942082
9  01-09-2000    2477000
10 01-10-2000    2527969
11 01-11-2000    2161170
12 01-12-2000    2175314
13 01-01-2001    2307525
14 01-02-2001    2196415
15 01-03-2001    2545863

library(signal)
library(shiny)
library(AnomalyDetection) #devtools::install_github("twitter/AnomalyDetection")
library(ggplot2)
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(googleVis)

shinyUI(dashboardPage(skin = "green",

                      dashboardHeader(title = "Anomaly Detection in Time series",
                                      titleWidth = 350),

                      dashboardSidebar(
                        sidebarUserPanel("Nishant Upadhyay",
                                         image = "nishantcofyshop.jpg"
                        ),

                        sidebarMenu(
                          menuItem("Data", tabName = "data", icon = icon("database")),
                          menuItem("Filters", tabName = "filter", icon = icon("filter")),
                          menuItem("Anomalies", tabName = "anomaly", icon = icon("check")),
                          #menuItem("Save Data", tabName = "save", icon = icon("save"))
                          menuItem("About The App", tabName = "Help", icon = icon("info-circle"))
                        )
                      ),


                      dashboardBody(
                        tabItems(

                          tabItem(tabName = "data",

                                  fluidRow(
                                    box(
                                      title = "Data scatter Chart",
                                      status = "primary",
                                      solidHeader = T,
                                      collapsible = T,
                                      width = 12,
                                      shinycssloaders::withSpinner(htmlOutput("dataChart"),type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 8),color = "red")
                                    )

                                  ),

                                  fluidRow(
                                    box(

                                      radioButtons(
                                        "data_input","",
                                        choices = list("Load sample data" = 1,
                                                       "Upload csv file" = 2
                                        )
                                      ),

                                      conditionalPanel(
                                        condition = "input.data_input=='1'",
                                        h5("Sample dataset of Lebron James basketball shots over the years")
                                      ),

                                      conditionalPanel(
                                        condition = "input.data_input=='2'",
                                        fileInput('file1', 'Choose file to upload',
                                                  accept = c(
                                                    'text/csv',
                                                    'text/comma-separated-values',
                                                    'text/tab-separated-values',
                                                    'text/plain',
                                                    '.csv',
                                                    '.tsv'
                                                  )),
                                        checkboxInput('header', 'Header', TRUE),
                                        radioButtons('sep', 'Separator',
                                                     c(Comma=',',
                                                       Semicolon=';',
                                                       Tab='\t'),','),
                                        radioButtons('quote', 'Quote',
                                                     c('None'='',
                                                       'Double Quote'='"',
                                                       'Single Quote'="'"),
                                                     '')
                                      ),
                                      title = "Select Dataset",
                                      status = "info",
                                      solidHeader = T,
                                      collapsible = T
                                    ),

                                    box(
                                      title = "Data",
                                      status = "info",
                                      solidHeader = T,
                                      collapsible = T,
                                      shinycssloaders::withSpinner(htmlOutput('contents'),type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 8),color = "red")
                                    )# end of box

                                  )## end of Fluid row

                          ), ## end of tab item 

                          tabItem(
                            tabName = "filter",
                            fluidRow(
                              box(
                                title = "Data Chart",
                                status = "primary",
                                solidHeader = T,
                                collapsible = T,
                                width = 12,
                                shinycssloaders::withSpinner(htmlOutput('dataChartFiltered'),type = getOption("spinner.type", default = 8),color = "red")
                              )
                            ),


                            fluidRow(
                              box(
                                title = "Filters",
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = T,
                                collapsible = T,
                                width = 4,
                                radioButtons("filt", NULL,
                                             c("None" = "none",
                                               "Butterworth" = "butt",
                                               "Type-II Chebyshev" = "cheby2")),
                                submitButton("Filter")
                              ),
                              box(
                                title = "Butterworth",
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = T,
                                collapsible = T,
                                width = 4,
                                textInput("buttern", label = "Filter Order", value = "3"),
                                textInput("butterf", label = "Critical Frequencies", value = "0.1"),
                                radioButtons("buttert", "Type",
                                             c("Low-Pass" = "low",
                                               "High-Pass" = "high"))
                              ),
                              box(
                                title = "Chebyshev",
                                status = "info",
                                solidHeader = T,
                                collapsible = T,
                                width = 4,
                                textInput("chebyn", label = "Filter Order", value = "5"),
                                textInput("chebyd", label = "dB of Pass Band", value = "20"),
                                textInput("chebyf", label = "Critical Frequencies", value = "0.2"),
                                radioButtons("chebyt", "Type",
                                             c("Low-Pass" = "low",
                                               "High-Pass" = "high"))
                              )
                            )
                          )

                        )  ## end of tab items
                      ) ##  end of Dashboard
)
)

shinyServer(function(input, output){

  dataframe<-reactive({
    if (input$data_input == 1) {
      tab <- read.csv("df.csv",header = T,stringsAsFactors = F)
    } else if (input$data_input == 2) {
      inFile <- input$file1
      if (is.null(inFile))
        return(data.frame(x = "Select your datafile"))

      tab = read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header,
                     sep = input$sep, quote = input$quote)

    }

    tt <- tryCatch(as.POSIXct(tab[,1]),error=function(e) e, warning=function(w) w)
    if (is(tt,"warning") | is(tt,"error")) {
      tab$Old = tab[,1]
      tab[,1] = as.POSIXct(1:nrow(tab), origin = Sys.time())
    } else {
      tab[,1] = as.POSIXct(tab[,1])
    }

    tab
  })

  output$dataChart <- renderGvis({
    if (!is.null(dataframe())) 
      gvisLineChart(dataframe()[,c(1,2)], xvar = colnames(dataframe())[1], yvar = colnames(dataframe())[2],
                    options = list(
                      crosshair.trigger = 'selection',
                      enableInteractivity = TRUE,
                      hAxis.maxTextLines = 10,
                      tooltip.trigger = 'none'
                    ))
  })

  output$contents <- renderGvis({
    if (!is.null(dataframe()))
      gvisTable(dataframe(), 
                options = list(page='enable'))
  })

  output$dataChartFiltered <- renderGvis({
    if (input$filt == "none") {
      return(NULL)
    } else if (input$filt == "butt") {
      bf <- butter(as.numeric(input$buttern), as.numeric(input$butterf), type = input$buttert)
      filtered = data.frame(timestamp = dataframe()[,1], 
                            count = as.numeric(filter(bf, dataframe()[,2])))
      gvisLineChart(filtered, xvar = colnames(filtered)[1], yvar = colnames(filtered)[2],
                    options = list(
                      crosshair.trigger = 'selection',
                      enableInteractivity = TRUE,
                      hAxis.maxTextLines = 10,
                      tooltip.trigger = 'none'
                    ))
    } else if (input$filt == "cheby2") {
      ch <- cheby2(as.numeric(input$chebyn), as.numeric(input$chebyd), 
                   as.numeric(input$chebyf), type = input$chebyt)
      filtered = data.frame(timestamp = dataframe()[,1], 
                            count = as.numeric(filter(ch, dataframe()[,2])))
      gvisLineChart(filtered, xvar = colnames(filtered)[1], yvar = colnames(filtered)[2],
                    options = list(
                      crosshair.trigger = 'selection',
                      enableInteractivity = TRUE,
                      hAxis.maxTextLines = 10,
                      tooltip.trigger = 'none'
                    ))
    }

  })

})
```

The problem i am facing is that once the shiny app is executed , the sample data is loaded properly as the this data is placed in the app folder in the directory (one can use R inbuilt data set or use the data i gave in the start) and subsequently all steps gets executed properly.

But if i want to upload some other csv file from local directory, the upload button selection does not get activated even after selecting it.But,in fact, if one goes to the second menu item in the sidebar panel i.e. filter tab and clicks on the filter button (under Filters box ) and then if i go back to Data menu in the sidebar panel again, i can see that now my upload csv file button has got activated and now i can browse the csv file in local directory and upload the same into the app and now everything works fine.

It seems somewhere the condition that makes the upload file button is not getting active initially when the app opens....

Need help to sort out the issue...Sorry for posting large chunk of code....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`conditionalPanel` and `submitButton` do not work well together. Replace your `submitButton("Filter")` with `actionButton("Filter", "")`.

**EDIT:**

As per the comment, for the plot to be generated only after the `actionButton` is clicked you can put `output$dataChartFiltered` inside `observeEvent` of `Filter` with `isolate` for `input objects as follows:

```
observeEvent(input$Filter,{
  output$dataChartFiltered <- renderGvis({
    if (isolate(input$filt) == "none") {
      return(NULL)
    } else if (isolate(input$filt) == "butt") {
      bf <- butter(as.numeric(isolate(input$buttern)), as.numeric(isolate(input$butterf)), type = isolate(input$buttert))
      filtered = data.frame(timestamp = dataframe()[,1],
                            count = as.numeric(filter(bf, dataframe()[,2])))
      gvisLineChart(filtered, xvar = colnames(filtered)[1], yvar = colnames(filtered)[2],
                    options = list(
                      crosshair.trigger = 'selection',
                      enableInteractivity = TRUE,
                      hAxis.maxTextLines = 10,
                      tooltip.trigger = 'none'
                    ))
    } else if (isolate(input$filt) == "cheby2") {
      ch <- cheby2(as.numeric(isolate(input$chebyn)), as.numeric(isolate(input$chebyd)),
                   as.numeric(isolate(input$chebyf)), type = isolate(input$chebyt))
      filtered = data.frame(timestamp = dataframe()[,1],
                            count = as.numeric(filter(ch, dataframe()[,2])))
      gvisLineChart(filtered, xvar = colnames(filtered)[1], yvar = colnames(filtered)[2],
                    options = list(
                      crosshair.trigger = 'selection',
                      enableInteractivity = TRUE,
                      hAxis.maxTextLines = 10,
                      tooltip.trigger = 'none'
                    ))
    }

  }) 

 })
```

Comment: It worked...Thank You so much for your valuable insight!

Comment: It seems my filter action button are redundant....its rendering even before clicking it...rendering should happen after clicking the filter action button...how can that be achieved?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand you, could explain in detail?

Comment: Or you could put `output$dataChartFiltered`  inside `observeEvent` of  `Filter` with `isolate` for `input` objects.

Comment: @Nishant, I've  edited my answer to show how its done. Hope it helps!

Comment: Awesome...Works.!..Learnt so much about shiny today.